# Detect selected table row by using radio button in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I would like to add radio button on each row of table in my struts2 application.And click the radio button and know the selected row.How should I define it? Here is my struts2 table

```
     <table>
       <tbody>
            <s:iterator var="list" value="toolSearchForm.toolInfoList">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <s:radio name="toolSearchForm.selectedCheckValue" list="checkValue"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><s:property value="categoryName" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="toolName" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="version" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="updateDate" /></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Know where? In action, javascript?

Comment: @AleksandrM in action

Comment: Submit form or execute ajax call to action.

Answer (score 0):

Add id attribute to the row

```
 <tr id="row__%{#list.index}">
```

so your first row will have id as row_0, second row as row_1 and so on

on the onclick of the radio button pass the index

```
 <s:radio id="check_%{#list.index}" onclick="selectRadio(%{#list.index})" name="toolSearchForm.selectedCheckValue" list="checkValue"/>
```

have this function in javascript

```
function selectRadio(rowIdIndex){
//get the row element using the index value
 var rowElement = document.getElementById("row_" + rowIdIndex);
//remove the element or hide the element as per your requirement
}
```